# How to fix 'sh: brew: command not found' in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, terminal

I'm making a command-line tool in Xcode, and want to call terminal commands with my C++ code.

I found the `system()` function can run terminal commands. And I know that the commands I want work in my Terminal. But these commands are not working the same way when I call them with `system()` in Xcode.

For example, I tried calling the brew command in Xcode.

```py
system("brew");
```

I expect the output to be the same as when I type `brew` into my terminal:

```cpp
Example usage:
  brew search [TEXT|/REGEX/]
  ...etc
```

but the actual output in Xcode is `sh: brew: command not found`.

**Why is `system()` acting differently than terminal? Should I be using a different function?**

Comment: `/usr/local/bin`, where `brew` is, is likely is not in the `PATH` environment variable. Try running it using its absolute path: `/usr/local/bin/brew`.

Comment: @cfillion Thanks this worked! Do you know how to add that to XCode so I don't need to write the absolute path each time?

Comment: also @cfillion can you add your comment as an answer so I can mark this solved? ty

Answer (score 1):

`system` does not load your shell's configuration files, and that's where `/usr/local/bin` is added to the `PATH` environment variable.
(That directory is not included by default on OS X.)

The simplest solutions are probably to either use the full path, or start XCode from the terminal so it inherits your shell's `PATH`.

(More details about how `PATH` works, and environment variables in general, can be found in any introduction to Unix-y systems.)

Comment: Great! I tried @cfillion 's absolute path and it worked. Is there a way I can add this to the `PATH` variable in XCode?

Comment: That depends on your system version. See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks) for suggestions. (I don't know how well the answers work now; I haven't felt the need to do this for years,)